# How to get footer to start on the 3rd page of the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to start footer on the a certain page and end at another.

We have a system were user creates a letter and is able to generate the letter based on the authorization number they use. With the CSS that was implemented, the footer is appearing in the bottom of each page when they preview the letter on Chrome, IE, etc . Although that is the desired goal for the footer to appear in the bottom of the pages, the footer should only appear at certain pages and end at another. The letter is not generated as a PDF (but viewed as DOM) and thus I am having a hard time to determine how to get the the footer to appear only at certain pages.

The following is the css and the html:

```
<style>

.footer {
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   height:30px;
   width:100%;
   background:#999;
}

/* FOR IE 6. Following will only work in IE */
* html .footer {
   position:absolute;
   top:expression((0-(footer.offsetHeight)+(document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop))+'px');
}
```

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 10pt; margin-top: 10pt">CMS does not discriminate in its programs and activities. To request this publication in an alternative format, please call 1-800-MEDICARE or email: <u>altformatrequest@cms.hhs.gov.</u></div>

<div style="margin-bottom: 10pt">The company does not discriminate on the basis of race, color, national origin, sex, age, or disability in health programs and activities.</div>

<div style="margin-bottom: 10pt">We provide free services to help you communicate with us, such as, letters in other languages or large print. Or, you can ask for an interpreter. To ask for help, please call the member toll-free phone number listed on your ID card.</div>

<div>ATENCIÓN: Si habla español (Spanish), hay servicios de asistencia de idiomas, sin cargo, a su disposición. Llame al número de teléfono gratuito que aparece en su tarjeta de identificación.</div>

<div style="page-break-before:always">
    <img src="http://oc2-reatest/OCUpgrade52/images/NDL_UnitedHealthCare_Senior(Mandarin).png" />
    <img src="http://oc2-reatest/OCUpgrade52/images/NDL_UnitedHealthCare_Senior(Mandarin).png" />
    <img src="http://oc2-reatest/OCUpgrade52/images/NDL_UnitedHealthCare_Senior(Mandarin).png" />
    <img src="http://oc2-reatest/OCUpgrade52/images/NDL_UnitedHealthCare_Senior(Mandarin).png" />
</div>

<span id="demo"></span>
```

The following is the JavaScript:

```
<script>
    var myObject = {
      footer:"<table width='100%' class='footer'><tbody><tr><td align='left'><span style='font-size: 12pt !important; font-weight: bold'>Form CMS 10003-NDMCP<br />IR_170224_155124</span></td><td style='font-size: 12pt !important; vertical-align: top; font-weight: bold; text-align: right'>OMB Approval 0938-0829 (Expires: 01/31/2020)</td></tr></tbody></table>",
      footers: function() {
        return this.footer;
      }
    }

    x = myObject.footers();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x; 
</script>
```

Is it possible, in JavaScript, to have footers appear on certain pages of the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

From your description it's not quite clear which pages you want the footer to display on and which not.

If you have a certain condition you just need to wrap the render code in it in your javascript. And a way to identify which page it is. You can do it via query param in the URL. Like this:

URL: http:yourdomain.com/page1?footer=no

A simple example could be:

```
<script>
    if (window.location.search.indexOf('footer=no') > -1) {
         x = myObject.footers();
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x; 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @ Aleks Sekowski: One example would be that the footer would need to start at page 3 and end at page 4. What way would I identify the page? I have been trying to add a class to the footer. For example, if it page 1, add the attr page1, if page 2, page2 and so forth. However, I am not sure how to achieve that

Comment: @ Aleks Sekowski: I tried your suggestion via query param in the URL: However, I am not able to do that template is created in the LetterTemplatePreview.aspx file which I am unable to modify the file

Comment: How can I determine what page it is if the letter generated is not generated as a PDF?

Comment: @ Aleks Sekowski: I have a question regarding your approach. Based on my understanding, this would only work if the letter is generated as a PDF. Because the letter is generated in the "letter print view", which essentially generated in html, would it read it as all one page?